# Can we have a way to view a random Question?

Tags: feature-request, questions

No, this isn't a random question. I want to SEE random questions!

Is there an easy way for the addition of "RANDOM" under the questions tab so you can cycle through random questions? Maybe I'll stumble upon one that I haven't read yet or know the answer to.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this is to use your browser's random function. This works in Chrome console:

```
window.location = 'http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 169215)
```

169215 is the currently highest ID post on Arqade according to data.SE, which is a few days out of date.

..but this runs the risk of running into a few 404s and deleted questions every once in a while.

Comment: Okay, so just turn this into a button that I can hit it over and over again. Easy, right?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you can add `javascript:window.location = 'http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 169215)` as a bookmark.

Comment: This does not actually do random *questions* - it does random *posts*. Slight difference.

Comment: @FEichinger true, but you will always have a random question on the page you land on, unless its 404, so it works for the purpose

Comment: Although, it should also be noted that if it does random posts instead of questions, there will be some weight towards questions with many answers.

Answer (score 4):

There's a web app called [Dice Stack](https://stackapps.com/questions/1643/dice-stack-find-a-random-question) which does exactly that!

... but unfortunately it is currently broken, maybe you should nudge the author to update it.